# How much current can a tin solder track handle?

Tags: soldering, high-current, solenoid-valve

I'm working on a DIY project where I need to control some 9V solenoid valves with an Arduino.
I don't have the tools to make a PCB myself, so I chose to work on perfboards.

Now, I have to connect power supply [(MeanWell )](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=HDR-60) to the step down regulator ([Polou D36V50F9](https://www.pololu.com/product/4094)) that powers the solenoid valves, and I'm doing it with a solder track.

With a solder track I mean a connection between perfboard pads made with standard solder tin.

My power supply is capable of sourcing 4.5 amperes at 12, with a total power of 54W.

- Can a solder track hadle all that power?
- How wide should it be?
- How thick?

**Note:**

My solenoid valves are latching, and this means that they need only a short pulse to open and close  (opposite polarity), and I can control them one at a time to minimize the current. But I want to be sure that my circuit won't burn in case the program does not work properly.

Comment: There are on-line calculators for this.

Comment: Yeah but they refer to PCB copper tracks. I'm doing it with tin, so the temperature acts differently

Comment: You can find a calculator where you can enter the conductivity value surely?

Comment: The question is not what your power supply is capable of, but what current your circuit actually draws. Also, what do you mean with 'I'm using tin'? Do you mean the track on the perfboard? That won't be tin, but 'tinned' copper. Same as a normal PCB.

Comment: The solder tracks only know about the current passing through them. They don't care about the power in the load. You only need to solve for current.

Comment: Oh i didn't know that soldering tin was the same of pcb tracks. Thank you.
And yes i know that i have to consider only the current passing through, but in the case of a theoretical progam fail the valves would draw up to 1,5 Amps each, and i have 5 valves. The current would be limited by the power supply to the max amount of 4,5Amp. I know that this is unecessary, but i prefer to be sure the everything works in the worst case

Comment: If it were me, I'd lay bare AWG18 wire along any paths on the board that need to carry 5 amps, just for the peace of mind. Solder melts at a MUCH lower temperature than copper.